# How to use Telerik MVC Grid for brand new data (as child of one-to-many relationship)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have the following entities:

```
create table Person (
    Id int primary key identity,
    Name varchar(80) not null
)

create table Contact (
    Id int primary key identity,
    PersonId int not null foreign key references Person(Id),
    Name varchar(80) not null,
    Relationship varchar(80) not null,
    Phone varchar(80) not null,
    Email varchar(80) not null
)
```

I would like to make a form in ASP.NET to *add* a brand new person and their contacts all at once, using a textbox for the person’s name and [Telerik MVC Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingbatch) for the contacts. E.g.,

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(person => person.Name) %>
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<EditableContact>() %>
```

---

However, since the person entity is not yet created until the form is submitted, how can Telerik Grid send data to the server when a contact record is added, edited, or deleted?

Ideally, I would like to have everything (person’s name and all of their contacts) sent to the server upon submission of the form.

---

Should I do something like `Session["UnsavedPerson"] = new Person();` when the view for the add-new-person-and-their-contacts page gets called?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could accomplish this. One way I might suggest is to use create a client-side representation of the complete model you wish to save, which would be basically a JSON representation of your model.

You could then use server binding for the data source (since it sounds like you would not actually be binding to anything yet), then add a client event handler for the OnSave event. In that event, you can get the values they entered, and map them to a JSON instance of the contact model.

Then, when you click some save button, you could submit that JSON model to an AJAX method to actually save your whole model.

```
<%= Html.Telerik()
      .Grid<EditableContact>()
      .Events(events => events.OnSave('contacts_OnSave')
      // rest of your grid configuration
      .Render();
      %>

<script type="text/javascript">

var model = { 
 Name:'',
 // etc.
 Contacts = []
};

function contacts_onSave(e) {
  model.Contacts.push(e.values);
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the grid from trying to post the new record, since we'll handle it later
}

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        model.Name = $('#Name').val();
        $.post('url/to/save', model, function() { alert('Saved successfully!'); });
    });
});

</script>
```

This, of course, is a rather crude example that could be optimized better, but I want to illustrate the idea of grabbing the values they inserted from the grid and using them later. You could certainly have the OnSave handler create a bunch of hidden inputs to make this page more POST compatible and allow you to make use of `$.fn.serialize`, but I leave that to you.